# How would I write water tiger vertically?

Tags: usage, characters, classical-chinese

I was born in the year of the tiger and water element, 1962. I want a vertical tattoo of that and wanted to make sure what I wanted was correct.

How would I write water tiger vertically in Chinese characters?

Comment: Use Google Translate to get the Chinese translation of "Water Tiger" Copy the characters and paste them on any app that has a vertical layout option (I use TextEdit, the option is under Format)

Comment: Does "Water Tiger" refer to something specifically?

Comment: It will depend when you were born in 1962: if you were born between January 1 and February 4, 1962, you're 辛丑, Metal Ox. From February 5 to January 24, 1963: 壬寅, Water Tiger.

Answer (score 2):

For the year 1962, assuming you’re using the Gregorian calendar, the first day of the first month of the lunar calendar was on 5th February. And spring commences (the first four-and-twenty solar terms) was on 4th February.

Depending on which “version” of traditional calendar used, on or after 5th February 1962 is associated to “[**壬寅**](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A3%AC%E5%AF%85)”.

“壬” alone is associated to the water element.

“寅” is associated to the Chinese zodiac “tiger”.

So, the correct term you wanted in vertical writing is:

`壬
寅`

Answer (score -2):

水 - water

虎 - tiger

Copy and paste the characters to a text or graphic editor to get -

[image]

Comment: this doesn't apply to zodiac though.

Comment: @zagrycha Water Tiger, in the Chinese zodiac, indicates a person born between 5 February 1962 and 24 January 1963., which was already covered by 水巷孑蠻.

Comment: 寅 is the chinese zodiac sign  though, not 虎

Comment: @zagrycha  **寅虎，十二生肖之一, 地支的第三位。** 生肖中的“虎”對應着十二地支中的寅，虎年即寅年，每十二年作為一個輪迴。比如公曆1962年基本對應的是虎年，即壬寅年。

Comment: @zagrycha Chinese zodiac sign - https://www.creativeartsguild.org/images/uploads/categories/12_Chinese_Zodiac_Signs.pdf. 地支，或称十二支 - https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9C%B0%E6%94%AF

Comment: I actually get the point you are making, although I still stand by what I said.  If someone is getting a tattoo with no context I think that using the regular tiger word is way more likely to be read as something not zodiac related where as 壬寅 or such is definitely zodiac.

Comment: @zagrycha As 水巷孑蠻 had covered it well, I was offering an alternative assuming the OP does not know the Chinese characters for "water tiger".

Answer (score -4):

In Chinese society, gang members often have tattoos. A common saying is "left dragon, right tiger," which means that a gang member has a dragon tattoo on his left arm and a tiger tattoo on his right arm. This is seen as a symbol of power and intimidation.
[image]

Comment: this is completey unrelated to OP's question